# Tracking frames and/or time during an animation

Tags: three.js

Can I call a function(one that will make another object visible/invisible) on a specific animation frame or time? I would like to have arrows describe the movement of the animation at certain times during the animation. While I can just make them visible when I start the animation and make them invisible when the animation stops, I would like to specify ranges inside the animation to do this

```
playPatientAnim: function (anim, callback) {
    var pending = 1;
    var me = this;
    var finish = callback ? function () {
        if (pending && !--pending) {
            callback.call(me, anim);
        }
    } : null;


    me.currentPatient.skinned.forEach(function (mesh) {
        mesh.animations.forEach(function(anim){
            anim.stop();
        });
    });

    me.currentPatient.skinned.forEach(function (mesh) {
        var animation = mesh.animations[anim];
        animation.stop();
        if (animation) {
            pending++;
            animation.onComplete = finish;
            animation.play();
        }
    });
    if (finish) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you doing your animation?

Comment: added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a mesh visible or invisible ( `mesh.visible = false; //or true` ). To change visibility at certain time you could use timestamp:
  `new Date().getTime()`  and calculate how you want to do the sequence of your animation.

Comment: Won't that be an issue if the frames of the animation are stopped by the page going out of focus? If the animation was looping?

Comment: well when tab is not focus animation not suppose to frozen in normal pages. if you change tab and youtube video is playing when you lose focus it is still playing until it is finished and  then it is stopped.